# Python passing a vaiable into payload 400 error

Tags: python, http, lambda

Hi I'm trying to loop through some values in a for loop in python3.8 (lambda) to create a few bitbucket pipline variables. To start with, just to prove my code works i run the following which goes through a loop of 2 values, creates a variable called "acc" and gives a 201 response and then for the second time in the loop the variable acc already exists so it returns a 409 which is great as i expect that

```
accounts=['123', '12345']

for acc in accounts:
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    payload='{"key": "acc","value":"apply","secured":"false"}'
    data = payload
    url = 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<workspace>/<project>/pipelines_config/variables/'
    headers = urllib3.util.make_headers(basic_auth='user' + ':' + 'Password')
    print(headers)
    headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
    print(headers)
    
    r = http.request('POST', url, headers=headers, body=data)
```

now if i change "acc" in the payload to actually be the variable im passing in it fails with a 400 error.

```
accounts=['123', '12345']

for **acc** in accounts:
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    payload='{"key": "'+ acc +'","value":"apply","secured":"false"}'
    data = payload
    url = 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<workspace>/<project>/pipelines_config/variables/'
    headers = urllib3.util.make_headers(basic_auth='user' + ':' + 'Password')
    print(headers)
    headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
    print(headers)
    
    r = http.request('POST', url, headers=headers, body=data)
```

i've tried nearly every combination i can think of including escaping / using double single quotes etc but gett no where.

how can i pass a variable from a loop into this payload ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm just not getting it, but why don't you simply use your acc variable instead of making it a string in your first example?

```
accounts=['123', '12345']

for acc in accounts:
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    payload='{"key": "'+ acc +'","value":"apply","secured":"false"}'
    data = payload
...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Trying to pass the var in using "'+ acc +'" results in a 400 error below

400
{'error': {'message': 'Bad request', 'detail': 'The request body contains invalid properties', 'data': {'key': 'variable-service.request.validation-error', 'arguments': {}}}}
END RequestId: 880f3a2e-239d-4f0a-a3b6-9dce55f47777

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured it out after hours of trying.
BitBucket doesn't allow variables to begin with numbers.
would have been nice if their documentation advised this of course !